# How to pass a list between two functions?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that's been modified in one function, and I want it to go to another function in order to be read and modified further.

```
def get_cards_player():
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    player1 = []
    player2 = []
    you_won = False #if u won, var is true, if u lose, var is false

    for i in range(5):
        player1_cards = deck.get_card()
        player1.append(player1_cards.get_name())

        player2_cards = deck.get_card()
        player2.append(player2_cards.get_name())

    print('Your Hand:',', '.join(player1))
    print('Opponent Hand:',', '.join(player2))
    return player1, player2

def calc_winner():
```

I want player1 and player2 lists in `get_cards_player` function to go to the `calc_winner` function so that I can read the list and do stuff with it.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you understand how arguments to functions work? Passing the lists to the function as an argument makes the most sense here

Comment: how would I do that? im a beginner srry

Answer (score 1):

`calc_winner` should take these lists as parameters. I purposely changed the names to highlight that parameters don't have to have the same name in different functions.

`get_cards_player` already creates and returns the lists, so no need to change. Again, to show the different ways you can do this, I'm remembering the tuple containing the two players and using that in the call.

```
def calc_winner(p1list, p2list):
    print(p1list, p2list)

players = get_card_player()
calc_winner(players[0], players[1])
```